# Retina-ready slideshow

Tags: photos, preview, display, slideshow

I'm looking for an easy way to view a simple slideshow of photos with 1x1 pixel ratio, with play/pause button. I want **1 image pixel to be equal to 1 retina screen pixel**, as shown by default with Preview. **The borders of the screen should be black** as in any simple slideshow (the images being smaller than 2880 pixels).

The default slideshows (Preview and QuickLook and iPhoto) upscales the images ! I don't want to pay for any software (Aperture or other), this slideshow can be done with javascript and a web browser !

Comment: Have you tried Preview's Full Screen mode (not Slideshow)? You can use View > Actual Size to turn off scaling.

Comment: (+1) The full screen mode actually gives the right ratio and borders, but can not be automated, it requires the user to press a key to view the next image.